# Cargo generate Error: access denied (os error 5)

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have no strength left.
I try to use command:

```
cargo generate --git https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-pack-template
```

To create project template, but i get some error

**Access is denied. (os error 5)**

Has anyone perhaps encountered this problem?

Thanks

Comment: On which OS? And are you sure you have write access to the folder where you're trying to create the project?

Answer (score 0):

I can replicate the same problem using Windows 11 with the latest cargo generate version (0.14.0).
I've fixed the problem using an older cargo generate release ([0.13.1](https://github.com/cargo-generate/cargo-generate/releases/tag/v0.13.1))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).